# docker-compose execute command in main service which depends on other services

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

In my project I have a `Dockerfile` with a `nodejs` image. On the `docker-compose.yml` file I have two services: `server` which builds from the `Dockerfile`, and `db` which uses a `postgres` image.

The `Dockerfile` gets the image, creates a directory for the project, runs `npm install` and sets `CMD ["npm", "start"]`.

The content of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "2"
services:
  server:
    build: .
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.2
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: devel
      POSTGRES_USER: devel
      POSTGRES_DB: devel

volumes:
  db_data:
```

In my project I am using `db-migrate` with `db-migrate-pg` driver and when I try to execute the migration I get the next error:7

```
[ERROR] Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1136:14)
npm info lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: Failed to exec migrate-up script
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! project-js@1.0.0 migrate-up: `db-migrate up`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the project-js@1.0.0 migrate-up script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-07-12T17_31_10_049Z-debug.log
```

The configuration for the database is correct because I can use it on PgAdmin. I don't know how to access the file that says the error because the container is stopped after it ends the execution.

EDIT:

This is the complete output from the named file in the error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'migrate-up' ]
2 info using npm@5.0.0
3 info using node@v8.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'premigrate-up', 'migrate-up', 'postmigrate-up' ]
5 info lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~premigrate-up: project-js@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~premigrate-up: no script for premigrate-up, continuing
7 info lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: project-js@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
10 verbose lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: CWD: /usr/src/app
11 silly lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: Args: [ '-c', 'db-migrate up' ]
12 silly lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle project-js@1.0.0~migrate-up: Failed to exec migrate-up script
14 verbose stack Error: project-js@1.0.0 migrate-up: `db-migrate up`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:283:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:887:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:208:5)
15 verbose pkgid project-js@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /usr/src/app
17 verbose Linux 4.8.0-58-generic
18 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "migrate-up"
19 verbose node v8.0.0
20 verbose npm  v5.0.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error project-js@1.0.0 migrate-up: `db-migrate up`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the project-js@1.0.0 migrate-up script.
24 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

From the `server` container point of view, postgres is here:

```
db:5432
```

Each container has its own network interface, hence each one has its own localhost.
`docker-compose` create a network for your containers and put them in it. As a bonus you get a DNS resolution, then they can talk each other using their service names.

---

> Q. I don't know how to access the file that says the error because the container is stopped after it ends the execution.

Do [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/):

```
last_stopped_container=$(docker ps -q -l)
docker cp $last_stopped_container:/root/.npm/_logs/2017-07-12T17_31_10_049Z-debug.log debug.log
cat debug.log
```

---

Also, use `depends_on` instead of `links` in order to get some dependecy startup:

```
depends_on:
  - db
```

And as I can see, you are running db-migrations at the very begining of the server startup; this could lead to an unavailability of the PostgreSQL in that short period of time. If it is as so, do this:

```
docker-compose up -d db
# wait just a few seconds
docker-compose up server
```

Which is not very elegant. So you will need to use a more robust solution: https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it. Download that script, put it in the server image and use as this:

```
  server:
    build: .
      command: /wait-for-it.sh db:5432 -- npm run #or whatever node command you have
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    links:
      - db
```

Comment: Do I need to add the port into the `db` line on `links` section?
I updated my question to add the output of the file.

Comment: @abaracedo, No, you don't. Also change links to depends_on as I posted

Comment: Which node.js file has you edited? It should be some configuration file

Comment: I have the `package.json` with a command `start` and two others for create and execute migrations. Then I have my `server.js` file which starts an `express` app.

Comment: You need to change `localhost:5432` to `db:5432`, have you done that?

Comment: I think that I am doing something wrong because it doesn't allow to execute the script. Using the `command` it is going to be executed every time I initialize the containers?

Comment: Yes, the command is indeed the process that runs containerized. Have you finally configured your app to point to postgres to db instead localhost?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now it says that the script `no such file or directory`. The command line is `command: /wait.sh db:5432 -- npm run migrate-up`

Comment: How did you copy it to the image? Dockerfile? `COPY wait.sh /wait.sh`?

Comment: I had the correct line in the Dockerfile but I wrote it wrong in docker-compose.yml. Now i can initialize the containers and when I try to execute a migration I get the same error I wrote in my question.